# Swift: making url from string relative to base url

Tags: swift, url, relative-path

Having simple endpoint enum, like:

```
enum TraccarEndpoint: Endpoint {

    case server

    var baseURL: URL {
        return URL(string: "http://demo.traccar.org/api")!
    }

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .server:
            return "/server"
        }
    }

    var url: URL {
        let path = self.path
        let baseURL = self.baseURL
        let url = URL(string: path, relativeTo: baseURL)
        return url!
    }
}
```

expecting self.url = "http://demo.traccar.org/server", but self.url = "/server -- ttp://www.traccar.org/api". What is that?

Comment: you can simplify your url property `var url: URL { return URL(string: path, relativeTo: baseURL)! }` Also no need to include slash in your server string `return "server"`

Answer (score 5):

It's the way an URL is described. Your url is correct don't worry. Print `url.absoluteString` to convince yourself

You can get absolute URL with `url.absoluteURL`

Comment: Not really, little slash made huge difference. When slash ('/server') was in path component I got error (using url parameter as URLConvertible in Alamofire.request call, BUT when I've included that slash to baseURL and removes it from path everything works!

Comment: And in both cases (Success and Failure) url.absoluteString was the same...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution moving the `/` from the path to the baseURL:

```
http://demo.traccar.org/api/
```

instead of

```
 http://demo.traccar.org/api
```

and: `server` instead of `/server`

Answer (score 1):

Below are a few examples of how `baseURL` and relative paths interact:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/v1/"];
[NSURL URLWithString:@"foo" relativeToURL:baseURL];                  // http://example.com/v1/foo
[NSURL URLWithString:@"foo?bar=baz" relativeToURL:baseURL];          // http://example.com/v1/foo?bar=baz
[NSURL URLWithString:@"/foo" relativeToURL:baseURL];                 // http://example.com/foo
[NSURL URLWithString:@"foo/" relativeToURL:baseURL];                 // http://example.com/v1/foo
[NSURL URLWithString:@"/foo/" relativeToURL:baseURL];                // http://example.com/foo/
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example2.com/" relativeToURL:baseURL]; // http://example2.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I copy your Code

```
enum TraccarEndpoint {

    case server

    var baseURL: URL {
        return URL(string: "http://demo.traccar.org/api")!
    }

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .server:
            return "/server"
        }
    }

    var url: URL {
        let path = self.path
        let baseURL = self.baseURL
        let url = URL(string: path, relativeTo: baseURL)
        return url!
    }
}
```

The url string is /server -- http://demo.traccar.org/api.

The different thing is TraccarEndpoint do not inheritance Endpoint.
Does EndPoint has baseURL String is "http://www.traccar.org/api" ?
If it is , you can see this web [Method Dispatch in Swift](https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2016/12/swift-method-dispatch/?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=email&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_114)

It can help you know the Method Dispatch about swift.